# Missing pid file running Tomcat 9.0.21

Tags: tomcat

Is there no longer any pid file in this newer Tomcat version ? Or is there propably any configuration option to activate it ? Platform OS is OpenSuse Leap 15.1

Answer (score 2):

Since I've recently faced exactly the same issue let me share my findings here.

First of all, take a look at those two issues:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63244
- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63041

In Tomcat 9.0.14 there were two changes - [1](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1848046) and [2](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1850829) - introduced that basically broke pid creation. That also prevents Tomcat from running as `systemd` service. Later it was fixed, but I wasn't able to find the exact version unfortunately. As per the [changelog](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/changelog.html) it should be the version 9.0.17 but as we are running Ubuntu 18 where the latest available Tomcat 9 package version is 9.0.16 I cannot check it.

There is also a way to fix it yourself if you want\can change `catalina.sh` script. Search for the following line (there are two of them):

`2\>\&1 \&\& echo \$! \>\"$catalina_pid_file\" \; \} $catalina_out_command "&"`

and change it to:

`2\>\&1 \& echo \$! \>\"$catalina_pid_file\" \; \} $catalina_out_command "&"`

Note the single ampersand symbol.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Tomcat to create a pid-file, then you need to make sure that the `CATALINA_PID` environment variable is set when calling `bin/catalina.sh` (or `bin/startup.sh`).

If you are using `systemd` with a config file, you may have to configure things differently because I think `bin/catalina.sh` is not used. Also, I'm pretty sure that using `systemd` obviates the need for ever using a pid-file. It's one of the things the systemd folks find abhorrent about traditional startup scripts IIRC.